# Using buffer or pszText member of LVITEM structure upon LVM_GETITEM

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

If I want to read a value from a certain item and sub-item in a list-view I do the following:

```
const int MAX_SIZE = 256;
char szBuffer[MAX_SIZE];

LVITEM lvItem = {0};
lvItem.iItem = rowIndex;
lvItem.iSubItem = subItemIndex;
lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_STATE;
lvItem.cchTextMax = MAX_SIZE;
lvItem.pszText = szBuffer;

// Get item
SendMessage(hListView, LVM_GETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvItem);

// Print value, which one always guaranteed to work?
std::cout << lvItem.pszText << std::endl;
std::cout << lvItem.szBuffer << std::endl;
```

Now, reading the [MSDN Documentation on LVM_GETITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774953(v=vs.85).aspx) we see that it says

> Applications should not assume that the text will necessarily be placed in the specified buffer. The control may instead change the pszText member of the structure to point to the new text, rather than place it in the buffer.

How do we know when it is safe to use our buffer (szBuffer in this example) rather than using

```
lvItem.pszText
```

directly?

Maybe we always have to do (or similar):

```
if(lvItem.pszText != szBuffer)
    snprintf(szBuffer, MAX_SIZE, "%s", lvItem.pszText);
```

to copy the value from the pszText of the LVITEM structure into
our buffer (after we have sent the LVM_GETITEM message of course).

Comment: Copying the data from `pszText` should be the safest bet. However, if you use `snprint` where the source and the destination is the same (i.e. when `lvItem.pszText == szBuffer`) is *undefined*. Why not simple check for that first, and copy if needed?

Comment: Okay, thanks. That's a good suggestion (see my edit).

Comment: You are using `snprintf` without actually formatting a string. If you merely want to copy a string, use [strcpy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663.aspx) instead, for example `strcpy(szBuffer, lvItem.pszText);`.

Comment: Yeah strcpy is better ofc, the snprintf came from me copy-pasting around stuff =)